# after running angular cli ng --prod local images will not work angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have local images stored in src/assets/img/ and when I running my code locally they show up fine.

My html looks like this:

```
  <img class="img-logo" src="./assets/img/deck-logo-black.png">
```

and this:

```
  <img src="./assets/img/download-app" class="center-block icon-appstore">
```

However after I run ng build --prod --aot and throwing the dist files into my s3 bucket the images do not display on my website.

Console Error looks like this:

```
GET https://websitename/assets/img/deck-logo-black.png 403 ()
GET https://websitename/assets/img/download%20app.png 403 ()
```

In looking for solutions to my problem I found posts where defining the img folder in the angular-cli.json under assets worked.

Therefore my angular-cli.json looks like this for assets:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "img"
  ],
```

Also running angular/cli version 1.0.0
I am not understanding why the images are not displaying if I defining the image folder in the assets[] in the angular-cli.json or why it is a 403 error in the console.

Any help/tips/suggestions to get towards a solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: Gave that a shot and still getting the same console errors.

Comment: i gave the ng build --prod --no-aot a shot but got the same errors

Comment: unfortunately same results. Are you thinking it has to do with my file path in the html? It is my understanding that when ng build --prod is run, the assets folder gets put at the root level. This leads my to believe that /assets/img/<filename> would work

Comment: I understood that the /assets are available and you get 403, so the browser cannot access the URL. Now that I reread your post, do you get /assets in /dist ? how about ng build alone?

Comment: Found the problem. I had the file structure wrong in my s3 bucket and the images weren't being found from the assets file. You question got me looking the right spot though. THANK YOU!

Comment: Happy you found!